# Translation not working for StripeIntegration_Payments

Tags: magento2, localisation, stripe, magento24

I tried to translate *Card •••• %1 has been deleted.* from **StripeIntegration_Payments**, but it's not working. I assume it's because of those bullets that should be escaped maybe, but I'm not sure.

My translation:
*"Card •••• %1 has been deleted.","My translation here","module","StripeIntegration_Payments"*

The path is good and everything else gets translated correctly, but this one is not.

Could someone help me out with this?

What am I missing?

Thank you.